# Torque and force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque

Does the force due to torque on the edge of a wheel depend on the mass of the the wheel or is it always $\tau / R$?[image]

Comment: You mention “force due to torque” but as drawn your force vector would be generating torque. Consider updating the wording and diagram... I don’t think the question can be properly answered as is.

Comment: @Floris If the engine of a car produces a torque about the wheel axle, then it wouldn't be wrong to think about this torque as causing the force at the contact with the road. There is no answer to whicj comes first anyways as they exist simultaneously.

Comment: @john Please edit your question to clarify what is causing or creating the torque T and force F. For example, are T and F both loads that occur on the wheel, such as a torque T that drives the wheel and F is resistance due to friction (in which case F should be in the opposite direction)? If F due to something wrapped around the wheel (a chain?) and is pulling on it, and T is the equivalent load (= R*F)? Without knowing this, there are two different answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A car engine puts effort into producing a torque about the wheel's axle. This torque makes the wheel turn.

If the wheel is heavy (large mass, thus large moment of inertia), then it is harder for the engine to produce this torque.

But if the engine succeeds in producing the torque, then that torque causes a force at the road (at the contact point between road and wheel). And the relation is:

$$\tau=rF_\perp$$

This expression always applies. And it does not involve the wheel mass. That mass influenced the effort required to produce the torque, but not the force caused by that torque.

The answer to your question is no.

---

Note that in other situations you might think og the torque being produced by the force. Such as when turning a bolt with a wrench. Then the situation is reversed. Then it takes effort to produce the force (effort by your hand for example). And the heavier the wheel, the larger the necessary effort.

Still, in this situation as well, the torque that this force causes does not depend on the mass, but again follows the expression above.

Comment: This answer is not correct if the wheel is accelerating.

Comment: For example, if a torque is applied to a uniform disk resting on the ground and the disk does not slip at its contact point, then the friction force that reacts to the applied torque will be the torque divided by 3/2 R. If instead it is a hoop, then the divisor will be 2R.

Comment: @LOLKlimateKatastropheKooks This is new to me. Do you have a link where I can look more into this?

Comment: You can look at my answer to this question. Take the mass of the vehicle to be the mass of the wheel. Take L1 and L2 to be zero and you basically have the problem of a wheel with an applied torque. You might also find this problem in any engineering mechanics textbook on dynamics.

Comment: But wheel mass _indirectly_ influenced the contact force caused (through a torque), if you completely ignore indirect relationships and Newton second law for rotation - then you make harm to your understanding of physics. You can't simply just separate those relationships, because they are indirectly _dependent_ variables and not independent ones.

Answer (score 1):

The torque due to a force is not dependent on the mass of the object it is acting on. It is dependent on the point you are taking the torque about. In general, the torque due to a force is the cross product of the position vector from the point you are taking the torque about to the point of application of the force and the force.

If your drawing is intended to represent a system of a force and a torque acting on the wheel, then in order to be in equilibrium the force should be pointing in the opposite direction. The drawing is correct if it is simply indicating the torque about the center due to the force acting tangentially to the rim of the wheel.

EDIT: Since you appear to be asking about a larger system, e.g. wheels attached to a car with torque supplied to the wheels by an engine, then this diagram and highly simplified analysis will perhaps better address your question. $m$ is the mass of the vehicle, $L_1$ and $L_2$ are distances from the front and rear wheels to the center of mass of the vehicle, $R$ is the radius of the wheels, $\tau$ is the torque supplied by the engine, $N_1$ and $N_2$ are the normal forces that the ground imparts on the wheels, and $F$ is the friction force on the wheel being driven by the engine (front wheel drive is being assumed here).

[image: Vehicle]

The car has no angular acceleration and let's assume we can neglect the rotational inertia of the wheels for the overall analysis of the angular momentum of the vehicle. Also note that the torque supplied by the engine to the vehicle is internal to the system and hence there is a balancing torque in the opposite direction from the car on the engine. 
So then the sum of the *external* torques on the vehicle about the center of mass of the vehicle is zero.

$-N_1 L_1+ N_2 L_2 -F h = 0$

where $h$ is the vertical distance from the ground to the center of mass of the vehicle.

There is no acceleration of the system in the vertical direction, so the sum of the forces in the vertical direction is zero.

$N_1+N_2-mg=0$

The forces in the horizontal direction lead to the acceleration of the vehicle in the horizontal direction $a$.

$F = ma$

Finally, if we analyze the front wheel on its own, then we do need to consider its rotational inertia.  We also note that the forces from the axel pass through the center of the wheel.  Then, the angular acceleration of the wheel is given by:

$\tau - FR = I \alpha$

where $I$ is the moment of inertia of the wheel about its center and $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration of the wheel.  If the wheel does not skid then the acceleration of the vehicle is related to the angular acceleration of the wheel as:

$a=\alpha R$

If you know the torque supplied $\tau$ then you can use these five equations to determine the normal forces on the wheels, $N_1$ and $N_2$, the friction force with the ground $F$, the acceleration of the vehicle $a$, and the angular acceleration of the wheels $\alpha$.

The force you were asking for is then:

$F=\tau/(R + I/mR)$

So, if the mass of the car times the radius of the wheels is much greater than the moment of inertia of the wheels, which is generally the case, then the force $F$ is well approximated by $\tau/R$.

If the wheels skid, then you need to introduce the coefficient of kinetic friction to the problem.

Comment: I was asking about the force due to torque because in car wheels the torque has 2 jobs: pushing on the ground with a force F and angularly accelerating the wheel.

Comment: The reaction force with the ground is then related to the torque and the acceleration of the system. It’s a more complicated situation than what you have drawn. Your simple formula is not valid if you are interested in the reaction force for a system that is accelerating.

Comment: How can I calculate the reaction force F if I have the torque and the radius of the wheel?

Comment: That does not provide enough information if the wheel and the system that the wheel is attached to is accelerating.

Comment: @John - I have edited my answer to include the analysis of a vehicle with torque supplied by an engine. I think this is more in line with what you are asking about.

Comment: $\tau - FR = I \alpha$, what ?? Where second opposing torque comes from ? Besides, if you had in mind opposing ground torque due to friction, then according to third Newton law $\tau - FR = 0$, because any action has same reaction.

Comment: @Agnius - The torque tau is the torque applied to the axle of the wheel which comes from the engine driving the wheel. This equation is not Newton’s third law, but rather statement that the sum of the moments about the center of the wheel equal its moment of inertia times it’s angular acceleration. The equation is correct.

Comment: @LOLKlimateKatastropheKooks I'm asking not about $\tau$, but about opposing torque with negative sign $-FR$, where does it come from ? You can't sum anything you wish, but you need to sum **real** forces / torques operating on the same body.

Comment: F is the friction force that the ground places on the wheel.  It is clearly shown in the diagram. The moment due to the friction force about the center of the wheel is FR and it is in the clockwise direction. Again, the equation is correct.

Comment: Then, you can't sum these things at all. Friction force operates on wheel, and wheel force (due to engine generated torque) operates on ground. So bodies on which forces operates ARE different. Thus you can't sum them.

Comment: Do you have a dynamics text book handy?  The sum of the moments about the the center of mass of a wheel is equal to the moment of inertia of the wheel about its center times the angular acceleration.  This is one of Euler's equations for rigid body dynamics. The engine places a torque on the axle and the axle that is attached to the wheel transfers that torque to the center of the wheel.  The friction force also places a torque about the center of the wheel.  This is basic mechanics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104566/discussion-between-lol-klimate-katastrophe-kooks-and-agnius-vasiliauskas).

Answer (score 0):

Force due to torque will not depend on the mass of the wheel.
If the mass of the wheel is  more, more amount of work needs to be done on the wheel. But we are not caring about that. 
Remember here we have produced the torque ( tau) ( that is the initial condition provided to us), now your formula will always be valid.

Comment: Thanks! But why is the force a tire exerts on the ground not equal to $\tau / R$?

Comment: In Newtown laws ( for rotation) you will get the same result eitherway. Either from force to torque or torque to force the same result is applicable.

Comment: Tau = F x r ,. Thats we know

Comment: @John - That is only the case if the tire is in equilibrium and only the torque and the force of the ground are acting on it. For a full analysis you also need the forces that the axle places on the wheel in addition to the torque from the axle. These forces will depend on the acceleration and mass of the car.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it does depend on wheel mass, but **indirectly**. Here is how =>

By definition torque is:
$$ \tau = r\,F_\perp $$
And Newton second law expressed for rotation is :
$$ \tau=I\,\alpha $$
where $I$ is moment of inertia and $\alpha$ is angular acceleration. Putting these equations together and solving for a force gives
$$ F_\perp = \frac{I\,\alpha}{r} $$
In your case, wheel can be seen as a solid disk, which has moment of inertia:
$$ I_\textrm{disk} = \frac{m\,r^2}{2} $$
Substituting moment of inertia back into force equation gives final solution :
$$ F_\perp = \frac{m\,r\,\alpha}{2} $$
So you need wheel mass $m$, radius $r$ and angular acceleration $\alpha$ to calculate resulting force. However, if you have already calculated/extracted wheel's torque, then you can calculate same thing by just $\tau\,/\,r$. Still you need to remember that torque according to second Newton law depends on rotating object moment of inertia. And moment of inertia depends on an object **mass** AND on object **shape**. You can look for common shapes moment of inertia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia). 

In a general case if body is continuous, then moment of inertia can be found integrating infinitesimal masses in a body:
$$ I = \int r^2 \,dm $$

**EDIT :**

If you need to include ground resistance effect on wheel, then just decouple net force :
$$ F_\perp = F_{\perp\text{engine}} - F_{\perp\text{resistance}} 
\\= F_{\perp\text{engine}} - \mu_{s}\,m\,g
$$

Comment: Your first equation shows that torque and force are not dependent on the mass, and none of your other equations show that force and totque are directly related by mass.

Comment: The answer to the OP question is no. Torque is simply force times the radius. Angular acceleration does depend on moment of inertia which, in turn, is a function of mass.

Comment: **This answer is incorrect**! What you have shown here is how big a force must be to produce a certain acceleration of the wheel. Thus the wheel's moment of inertia is involved. But, let's say that a car engine produces a torque about the wheel axle. That torque will try to make the wheel turn. But the surface is preventing the wheel from turning, and thus this torque creates a force at the surface (at the contact point). This force *only* depends in the torque - it doesn't depend on how heavy the wheel is. A heavier wheel...

Comment: ... might make it harder for the engine to produce the torque, but when that torque is produced, the wheel mass doesn't interfere anymore. The torque then in turn creates a force regardless of the wheel mass. And the relation is: $$\tau=rF$$ which does not include mass.

Comment: @Steeven I think you completely ignore Newton second law for rotation. That contact force as you mentioned depends on torque. And torque induced depends on moment of inertia of wheel and angular acceleration. If engine induces _same_ angular acceleration to more massive wheels, then this means it has produced **greater torque**.

Comment: @BobD OP asks not about torque, but how to calculate contact force.

Comment: @JohnHoltz Then you completely ignore Newton second law for rotation too ...

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas. You do make a valid point, but something is still wrong. It is not clear from the OP whether T and F are applied loads, or whether one is a load and the other is the equivalent due to the load. For example, T could be the torque applied to the  wheel and F is the resistance (drawn in the wrong direction) that opposes the T. In this case, your answer is wrong because the real equation would be (sum of torques) = (T-r*F) = I*alpha. If F is the only applied load and T is not a torque applied to the wheel but just the result of r*F, T=r*F=I*alpha.

Comment: @JohnHoltz I've included ground resistance effect, check my edit

Comment: OP asked "does the force due to torque depend on the mass of the wheel, or is it always equal to $\frac {\tau}{R}$?"  It seemed fairly clear to me that based on OP's wording, they want to know if the equation $F = \frac {\tau}{R}$ always holds by the sounds of it.  Doing substitutions to remove torque doesn't really show that the force doesn't always equal torque over radius; it just shows that torque over radius can be represented by something equivalent that includes mass instead of torque.

Comment: @JMac It's not that simple. Yes, torque is always defined as $\tau=F_\perp\,r$. And yes, force due to torque depends on mass of wheel, **indirectly** as I've shown. You can't ignore indirect relationships between variables. If OP has asked if wheel mass is involved somehow - I've showed HOW. Nothing more to add.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas And based on OP's wording I think this answer might just confuse them more.  They asked "Does the force due to torque on the edge of a wheel depend on the mass of the the wheel **or** is it always τ/R?"  I think at very least you should make it clear that the relationship is _indirect_, or else I don't think this is a helpful answer.

Comment: So ? The "or" conjunction can just show as well that OP has over-simplified things in physics. Even Einstein has famous quote "_Everything Should Be Made as Simple as Possible, But Not Simpler_". So indirect relationships, MUST be introduced to students learning physics, IMHO.